# Constructor wont run it's code

Tags: java, android, constructor, game-loop

I want to run a gameloop code inside my `GameLoop` class constructor in my activity, but it seems that it got no respond.

I've tried to put the code inside the `OnCreate` method instead of a new class and that worked.

My Activiy Class:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {
private Button btnHertz;
private TextView textView1;
private GameLoop gameloop;

private int hertz = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    gameloop = new GameLoop();

    btnHertz = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnHertz);
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testTextView1);
}

public void testUpdate(){
    hertz++;
    textView1.setText(Integer.toString(hertz));
}
```

GameLoop Class:

```
public class GameLoop {
private GameActivity gui;

public GameLoop() {
    gui = new GameActivity();
    ScheduledExecutorService exec = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gui.testUpdate();
        }
    }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Comment: Why are you making object of an Activity?

Comment: Laalto solution is correct for your reference.

Answer (score 3):

```
gui = new GameActivity();
```

The activity object you're passing updates to is different from the one that displays your UI.

Never instantiate activities yourself with `new`. Their lifecycle methods won't be invoked and they won't be good for anything. In this case you'd get an NPE at `textView1.setText()` since `onCreate()` has not been run.

Instead, pass a `GameActivity` reference as an argument to `GameLoop`, e.g.

```
... new GameLoop(this)
```

...

```
public GameLoop(GameActivity gui) {
```